# How to retrieve data in the template from a custom MariaDB connector? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have implemented the following connector following the MariaDB documentation. [Documentation](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/)

This is my db.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import mariadb 

conn = mariadb.connect(
    user="user",
    password="",
    host="localhost",
    database="db")
cur = conn.cursor() 
    
def get_some_data():
    cur.execute("SELECT some_id FROM `db`.some_data")
    sid = []
    for some_id in cur: 
        sid.append(some_id)
    return sid

conn.close()
```

So far everything is clear, what I am not clear about is...how can I show in a html select a list with the values obtained from the query to the database on my django web page?

Should I create a function in `views.py` and have it return something like this ?:

```
from db import get_some_data
def retrieve_from_db(request):
   #some code here
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Do I need a `context`?

Let's say my `index.html` is the following, how could I call `retrieve_from_db(request)` from the template and make this function call `get_some_data()` and display this information on the web?

`index.html`

```
    {% extends "../base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    {% block content %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}
    //Some form to retrieve the data from the .py scripts
    <form id="retrieve_db" action="someaction?" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        {% someforloop? %}
        <select name="myIdList" id="myIdList">
          <option value="{{ some_id }}">{{ some_id }}</option>
        </select>
        {% endforloop %}
      </div>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Let's say I want the values to be displayed in the list: `myIdList`

I think I understand the concepts separately, but I need to know how to connect the pieces of the puzzle.

If someone can help me with a 'skeleton' of how the entire cycle could be implemented that would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already moving in right direction.
Put the data to the context variable and pass it to render method with request and template name.

```py
from db import get_some_data


def retrieve_from_db(request):
   some_ids = get_some_data()
   context = {'some_ids': some_ids}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And now in template iterate over your ID's:

```py
 <div class="form-group">
     {% for some_id in some_ids %}
        <select name="myIdList" id="myIdList">
          <option value="{{ some_id }}">{{ some_id }}</option>
        </select>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

As for calling a function from template - in case you described it doesn't seems you need that, but in general you can't call function from template, but can use [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). Using this you'll simply pass request to it (you'll need to add it in context first) and get the result in template.

Comment: I tried your code and it is not working. Do I have to put the select inside a <form> or it's not necessary?

Comment: It depends on what exactly is not working?

Comment: It works if I put it inside of a form, is it possible to retrieve the data automatically when the user visit the index.html without perform any actions like pressing a submit button? Show automatically retrieve the data from the function and display it.